# Stereo problems on Linux using Java 7 - how to change the GC of a component after it has been added to a parent

Tags: java, opengl, canvas, awt, stereo-3d

I have an AWT canvas contained within a JPanel and displayed on screen. I currently use Java 7 update 45 and run on Red Hat 6.

When the user requests an openGL stereo capable canvas, i remove the existing canvas, create a new canvas that chooses a stereo visual and sets the appropriate GraphicsConfiguration on the canvas. The problem is, with new changes made in Java 7, when this canvas is added back to the JPanel, the GraphicsConfiguration(GC) of the Jpanel overwrites the GraphicsConfiguration of the Canvas.

This happens in *java.awt.Container.addImpl()* where it calls the package scoped method *Component.setGraphicsConfiguration()*.

I am currently using Reflection on this package scoped method to call the method from my code and change the GC on the canvas.

Is there any better solution than this ? In other words, how to change the GC of a component after it has been added to a parent ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do not change the GC at all. Instead just try to create a stereo capable GC and allow fallback to non-stereoscopic GC. If that succeeds enable the stereoscopic rendering path and menu entries.

Comment: I'm afraid that still wouldn't solve the problem. Even if i start with a stereo capable GC, when i add it to its parent(JPanel), the GC gets overwritten in the Container.add() method.

Answer (score 1):

The Stereoscopic regression caused by the JDK 7 AWT changes is reported in and worked on in the following bugreport:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8036875 - Component.setGraphicsConfiguration() breaks some 3D applications

A workaround made by "babor" for Java3D Canvas3D users is to override the Canvas3D hierarchyChanged method and update the topmost component using reflection to use the stereoscopic graphics configuration.
http://forum.jogamp.org/Java3D-stereo-tp4029914p4031792.html